# any sdk available for ITSO Android?

Tags: android, nfc

I searched with the help of google but found nothing concrete regarding how it is implemented.

I found the apps which reads ITSO smart cards and found the following apps to have found a solution: http://www.londonbanter.co.uk/london-transport/13401-itso-android.html

Would any of you know how I could proceed to implement this? Your inputs are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ITSO specification is Crown Copyright, so you can get the actual specification from here: https://www.itso.org.uk/

Reading an ITSO card on Android is quite simple.  Once you've detected an NFC card, check the technology.  I've only used DesFires, but this should be a similar method for all card types.

Once you have an NFC context and you know it's a DesFire, you need to select the ITSO application (ID = 0x16, 0x02, 0xa0), from there you just read the sectors and decode them according to the above spec.

ITSO applications have an ITSO Directory which contains the card number (ISRN), and a list of the products (IPEs) that are on the card with their expiry dates.  There's a sector chain table that you follow to get to the data files for each product.

The products themselves are quite simple, with very few real parameters to decode.  Check the IFR for each product and just decode the byte stream.

You'll firstly need to know how to send APDU commands to the NFC reader.  For example, to select the ITSO application you'd send these bytes 0x90, 0x5a, 0,0,3, 0x16, 0x02, 0xa0.  To read the directory you'd send 0x90, 0xbd, 0,0, 7, 0x0f, 0,0,0,0,0,0 (sector 15), etc..

Worth noting is that all ITSO data is freely readable, but to ensure it's genuine you'll need to check the seals and to do this you'll need access to the security keys, which you won't have. Similarly, you can write data to a card that looks like an ITSO application, but without the correct seals it will fail to work on real devices.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you come up with something to add to your original answer, don't respond by comment. Instead, edit your answer.

Comment: I get a command length error when running your commands? Can you help? What is the correct command length?

Comment: Hi J.  I've fixed the example above.  The command length for the Selection Application command in this instance should have been 3, not 4.

Comment: Thanks Tony, shortly after posting this comment I managed to find very concise documentation APDU command structure :)